Azure web app is returning 404 Error code
I deployed a spring boot application written in Kotlin with version 3.1.10 on the Azure app service. The app is live, it shows the default page saying, "Your app service is up and running. Time to take the next step and deploy your code." I deployed using Terraform.
Deploying the spring boot application with the.jar file used in my cicd.yml automates the whole process, but when I try to reach out to the service, it shows me an error of 404 Not Found.
Runtime Stack
Java 17 Tomcat
Does anyone have an idea?
The solution that I have already tried.

ApplicationInsight_JAVA_EXTENSION = 3.4.10

(https://stackoverflow.com/1
Here is my cicd.yml
name: hello

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout Sources
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup Java
      uses: actions/setup-java@v3
      with:
        distribution: 'temurin'
        java-version: '17'

    - name: Build Project
      run: mvn clean install -DskipTests

    - name: Upload Artifact for Deplyoment Job
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        name: microservice
        path: ${{ github.workspace}}/target/*.jar

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Download Artifacts from build Job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: microservice

      - name: Deploy Microservice to Azure App Service
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: abc-01
          publish-profile: ${{secrets.AZURE_PUBLISH_PROFILE}}
          package: '*.jar'



Check the controller mappings to make sure that the path (application URL) you are trying to access match the mappings in your application.
Verify that the application is listening to the correct port. You can configure your application to listen to the required port by adding the setting  WEBSITES_PORT=<port_number> in Azure App Service=>Application Settings.
Navigate to KUDU site of the App Service(https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net), site/wwwroot and check the jar file is deployed and available.



Check the logs in LogStream of the application in the KUDU site(https://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream) of the Azure App Service:



I have created a Spring Boot Application Kotlin with Getmapping "/hello"(as you mentioned in the screenshot).
Code Snippet:
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}
@RestController
class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun index(@RequestParam("name") name: String) = "Hello, $name!"
}


Deployed to Azure App Service using GitHub actions.
GitHub Workflow:

name: Build and deploy JAR app to Azure Web App - <app-name>

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Java version
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '17'

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn clean install

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app
          path: '${{ github.workspace }}/target/*.jar'

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: java-app

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: '<app-name>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_DC23D1D6912C486A94D72B8949EFE9DE }}
          package: '*.jar'

Output:

